# Dealing with changed hashes when building open-source packages in-house

Tags: opensource

My plan is to start building the open-source packages from their sources and use organization's security resources like SAST tools to detect security issues in them.

The good thing that I see coming out of this effort is better security, especially with some of the lesser known, smaller open-source projects that are not built with security in mind. The organization can then create pull-requests to fix the discovered issues as a giveback to the open-source community.

However, I'm afraid that the hashes of the generated artifacts will change and automated tools like Whitesource used to detect known vulnerabilities and licenses for opensource packages might stop working.

Has anyone faced such an issue? Is there a middle ground where we can have the perks of both the strategies?

Comment: What prevents your from building and analizing the packages only on a test platform and using the official modules on the production platform?

Comment: @SergeBallesta: We have more than a hundred products in the organization, each using hundreds (some even thousands) of open-source packages in their portfolio. With so many packages, using a test platform doesn't inspire confidence. I can see it getting out of hand quickly. What I'm trying to do is create an official workflow that our product teams can adopt. I know it'll be a good effort but I'm having a lot of doubts too.

Answer (score 0):

As your avatar is a penguin I am assuming you are using Linux.
The big Linux distros like Debian or Redhat have dedicated Security teams that publish which versions of the software they package is vulnerable to every CVE.

So instead of relying on the hash (IMHO a flawed concept that makes Whitesource unusable for opensource) rely on the version number + distro patchlevel to identify vulnerabilities.

The drawback is of course, you have to rely on packages that your distro packages, but if a package is missing you might just submit your package upstream.